# I want to integrate an existing app with quickbooks, but don't want to publish it

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I have developed a PHP application that receives input from Sales Managers and is analyzed in the application.  The Admin user of this app wants to be able to look at the sales/estimates that are posted to the app and sync the data with his online Quickbooks account.

I downloaded the quickbooks-php sdk from github (https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/) and I used the example app folder and figured out everything I needed.  When I read about putting this into production, all the documentation on the intuit site says that I need to publish my app to the Quickbooks Apps.com.  Is it possible to only include the posting-to-quickbooks functionality in my existing app?

Or do I need to publish a stand-alone app and THEN fit that into my existing one?

Comment: Are you using the web-connector?  I did an integration with the web-connector 3 years ago ( never published it ) and the intuit police never came for me.

Comment: No I am using consolibyte's quickbooks-php devkit. Good to know about the web-connector though.  I got the answer I was looking for from Keith Palmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I read about putting this into production, all the documentation on the intuit site says that I need to publish my app to the Quickbooks Apps.com.

No, it doesn't.

All you need to do to go to production is click a button within your app settings on Intuit's developer site, fill out a few fields, and swap out your tokens.

Here's a copy/paste from [Intuit's website](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0008_release_your_app_to_production) that explains what you need to go to production:

> *What you need to go to production*
> To get your production keys, some basic app details need to be in place.  Make sure you've completed the following fields on your app's Development  Settings tab:
>
> - Application Name
> - End User License Agreement URL
> - Privacy Policy URL
> - App URL
> - Host Name Domain
> - Disconnect Landing URL

Notice that no-where in that list does it say you need to "publish to Apps.com".

If you *wanted* to publish to Apps.com you could. But it's not mandatory. Just click the tab in your app settings and fill out the fields. If they don't apply to you, just make them up and put a random URL in.

> Is it possible to only include the posting-to-quickbooks functionality in my existing app?

Yes, of course.

Comment: This was very helpful.  So is the [Test your app for technical review](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api/0030_publishing_and_marketing_your_app/0005_test_your_app) only when publishing an app to Apps.com?

Comment: Correct, the technical review is only if you're publishing on Apps.com. If you're publishing on Apps.com there's a technical review, security review, marketing review, OpenID implementation, etc. etc. etc. that you have to deal with. If you're just "privately publishing" you just click a couple of buttons and you're done.